# Discord .log file reader bot - loop attribute cannot be accessed in non-async contexts

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am new to Python and am trying to get a Discord bot running that reads a .log file and outputs the contents of that file to a Discord channel.

I'm getting this error when attempting to run my code:

AttributeError: loop attribute cannot be accessed in non-async contexts. Consider using either an asynchronous main function and passing it to asyncio.run or using asynchronous initialisation hooks such as Client.setup_hook

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
#!/bin/python3 -u 
import os
import time
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
import re
import asyncio

load_dotenv()
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+123+', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('CC_to_Disc started on bot {0.user}'.format(client))
    
async def cc_to_disc():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel(int(os.getenv('channel')))
    file_to_watch = os.getenv('cclog')
    oldline = " "
    login_ptrn_rank = "<col=ef5050>(.*?)</col>"
    login_ment = ""
    
    try:
        while 1:
                await asyncio.sleep (0.2)
                with open(file_to_watch, 'r') as f:
                        lines = f.read().splitlines()
                        last_line = lines[-1]
                
                login_ment = re.search(login_ptrn_rank, last_line)
                
                if login_ment:
                    last_line = str("[Ten Talk] " + login_ment.group(1))
                    login_ment = ""
                    
                if last_line.endswith("You have left the channel."):
                    last_line = "TenTalkBot was disconnected. Attempting to reconnect..."
                    
                if last_line.endswith("To talk in your clan's channel, start each line of chat with // or /c."):
                    last_line = "TenTalkBot has been reconnected"
                    
                last_line = last_line.replace("Â", "")
                last_line = last_line.replace("<img=2>", os.getenv('ironman'))
                last_line = last_line.replace("<img=3>", os.getenv('uim'))
                last_line = last_line.replace("<img=10>", os.getenv('hcim'))
                last_line = last_line.replace("<img=41>", os.getenv('gim'))
                last_line = last_line.replace("<img=22>", "")


                if last_line != oldline:
                        await channel.send(last_line)
                        oldline = last_line
    except: 
        client.loop.create_task(cc_to_disc())

client.loop.create_task(cc_to_disc())
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

I've also tried replacing the last few lines with this:

```
    except: 
        asyncio.create_task(cc_to_disc())

@client.event
async def loop():
    asyncio.create_task(cc_to_disc())   
    asyncio.run(loop())
client.run('TOKEN')
```

Which seems to help with the original error, but then nothing happens with my bot. I'm not able to tell if it is even able to access or read the .log file properly.